# Possible to 'exit' racket prematurely

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

To short-circuit a C function (for example, for testing purposes), I can put an early `return` in there. For example:

```
int main(void) {
    puts("Hello");
    return;

    ...bunch of other code...
}
```

Or do a `sys.exit(0)` in python. Is there a way to do this in DrRacket / Scheme? As often I will have a workbook with a few hundred lines of code and I only want the top few functions to run before exiting. For example:

```
#lang sicp

(define (filtr function sequence)
  (if (null? sequence) nil
      (let ((this (car sequence))
            (rest (cdr sequence)))
        (if (function this) (cons this (filtr function rest))
            (filtr function rest)))))
              
(filtr  (lambda (x) (> x 5)) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))   
     
(exit)  ; ?? something like this I can drop in to terminate execution?

...200 more lines of code...
```

Is there a way to do that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#lang racket` can do that with the function named... `exit`. Try:

```
#lang racket

(display 1)
(exit 0)
(display 2)
```

`#lang sicp` doesn't have `exit`, but you can require it from Racket:

```
#lang sicp

(#%require (only racket exit))

(display 1)
(exit 0)
(display 2)
```

Early return from a function can be done using continuation. For example, with the `let/cc` operator:

```
#lang racket

(define (fact x)
  (let/cc return
    (if (= x 0)
        1
        (begin
          (display 123)
          (return -1)
          (display 456)
          (* x (fact (- x 1)))))))

(fact 10)
;; display 123
;; and return -1
```

Or equivalently, with `call-with-current-continuation`, which exists in both `#lang racket` and `#lang sicp`:

```
(define (fact x)
  (call-with-current-continuation
   (lambda (return)
     (if (= x 0)
         1
         (begin
           (display 123)
           (return -1)
           (display 456)
           (* x (fact (- x 1))))))))
```